# Set an input value from jQuery function

Tags: jquery, forms, input

I'm simply trying to set a value for an input but it doesn't work. Here is my jquery function :

```
function display_form() {
    try {
        $('#start_date').val('2012/08/21');
    } catch (e) {
        alert('error');
    }

   // window.alert($('[name=start_date]').val()); (shows "undefined")
   $('#add-event').show();
}
```

This is how display_form is called:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view)
            {     
                date_format = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    display_form();
                    return false;

                },
            events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myLogin%40gmail.com/public/basic'
        });
    });
```

This shows "undefined". 
Here is my form :

```
<input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text" size="6" />
```

Should I put somewhere the id of the form that I want to use? I just followed what is said in the documentation of jquery but it doesn't seem to work.
Could anyone help me ?

Comment: have you call display_form() somewhere?

Comment: @user1499229 check my solution below. Your code should work fine

Comment: are you sure the calendar plugin does not add another input or changes the name /class of yours?

Comment: Could you tell me please how can I check this?

Answer (score 1):

This will help

```
window.alert( $('input[name=start_date]').val() ); 



function display_form() 
    {   try {
        $('#start_date').val('2012/08/21');
        }catch (e){
                     alert('error');
                 }

       window.alert( $('[name=start_date]').val() ); 
       }

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#press').click(function() {
  display_form();
  });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Codesesn but I don't understand how the call of display_form would be done if I put $('#press').click. Actually, it is display form which would display the form after setting the start date value

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<input id="start_date" name="start_date" type="text" size="6" />
<button id="press">Press</button>
```

### JavaScript

```
function display_form() {
    try {
        $('#start_date').val('2012/08/21');
    } catch (e) {
        alert('error');
    }

    window.alert( $('[name=start_date]').val() ); 
}

$('#press').click(function() {
    display_form();
 });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FT4C9/1/)

Comment: it still not working for me. Actually display_form is called from another function.And I checked the call with putting an alert in the beginning of the function !

Comment: Could you provide a little more code so that I understand what exactly is happening.

Comment: can you do `console.log('something')` inside `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ })` and check if it logs something in console.

Comment: console.log doesn't show anything but all what I put inside dayClick is executed.